# Do foreign sanctions on US individuals compel US banks and businesses to cut ties with them or not doing business with them?

Tags: united-states, china, sanctions

Can a foreign country's sanctions on US individuals compel the US banks or companies to cut ties or not do business with them (even on US soil)?

For e.g. China, in January, [sanctioned](https://www.cnbc.com/2021/01/20/china-sanctions-pompeo-obrien-azar-and-other-trump-administration-officials.html) Mike Pompeo, John Bolton and many other Trump administration officials. The sanctions' details say that "any institution or entity associated with them will be blocked from doing business in China".

So for e.g. say that Mike Pompeo has a bank account in JPMorgan or any other banks who do business in China. So does that mean that JPMorgan or others will be banned from doing business in China? Also, wouldn't they ever finance/do business with Pompeo even on US soil and freeze his account which is physically on US soil? And does that mean JPMorgan is automatically barred from doing business in China because that's what Chinese sanctions mean and it also can't freeze Pompeo's account as it has a legal obligation to him under US law?

More interestingly, the details also include "any entity". So, will Pompeo not be able to buy goods/services or do anything with them? The details also include "institution". So will no university/college/organization be able to employ them even on US soil or anywhere globally? And what about any third party (non-US, non-Chinese) institution or entity?

Does that also mean Pompeo and others sanctioned can't be employed in a US/foreign company that has business in China?

Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: The answer is depending on China's determination and will to make it difficult for the livelihood of the named persons, which nobody can speculate.

Comment: @r13 That sounds like China's intent. They'd probably like to imprison them. But since they can't, they'll just use pressure tactics to make their professional and financial lives terrible.

Comment: I guess Donald Trump is a few dollars poorer now, as the Chines might have frozen his interests/holdings in China if this NYT/CNN report is true. https://www.cnn.com/2020/10/20/politics/trump-china-taxes-financial-records/index.html

Comment: I wonder what would happen if Mr. Pompeo is detained by the Chinese on a business trip :)

Comment: I don't want to distract the attention on this matter, but couldn't stop to think what would happen if Trump, or Pompeo, is elected to be the next President :)

Comment: Yeah, they sanctioned the Trump admin officials after they were no longer in power. How "courageous" of China...

Comment: Somewhat more courageously, in March China hit back at EU sanctions (related to China's treatment of the Uighurs) with sanctions of their own on EU personnel https://www.fmprc.gov.cn/mfa_eng/xwfw_665399/s2510_665401/t1863896.shtml So this seems like a tit-for-tat strat they are now using.

Answer (score 3):

Potentially, yes. It would be interesting to find out how China draws the list of associated entities, and if a major US bank would rather retain their ties with China or with a former administration official. The US used such sweeping sanctions in a few cases, like Iran and North Korea, but then forgoing business with North Korea is usually no big deal.

As I understand the news reports, in this case the Chinese sanctions are **not** that sweeping. They would hit companies owned by the listed individuals, however.